# Проверка нажатия на стрелки в меню

Tags: c, меню

```
    char choice;
    int start_menu_toggle[4];
    register int i,j,k;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        start_menu_toggle[i]=7;
    }
    int tmp=3;
    start_menu_toggle[tmp]=240;
    system("cls");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
    printf("\tВход\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[3]);
    printf("Вход как главный администратор\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[2]);
    printf("Вход как администратор\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[1]);
    printf("Вход как пользователь\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[0]);
    printf("Выход\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
    for (choice=getch();choice!='\r';choice=getch()){
        if (choice==0xE0 || choice==0 || choice==224){
        printf("Arrow key\n");
        system("pause");
        }
        choice=getch();
        if (choice!=72 && choice!=80){
        continue;
        }
        switch (choice){
            case 72:
                if (tmp<3){
                    start_menu_toggle[tmp]=7;
                    tmp++;
                    start_menu_toggle[tmp]=240;
                }
                break;
            case 80:
                if (tmp>0){
                    start_menu_toggle[tmp]=7;
                    tmp--;
                    start_menu_toggle[tmp]=240;
                }
                break;
        }
        system("cls");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
        printf("\tВход\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[3]);
        printf("Вход как главный администратор\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[2]);
        printf("Вход как администратор\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[1]);
        printf("Вход как пользователь\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), start_menu_toggle[0]);
        printf("Выход\n");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
    }
    switch (tmp){
        case 3:
            enter_perm='s';
            if (enter()){
                ban_flag=0; ban_count=0; ban_time=0; ban_flag_refresh();
                a_menu();
            } else{
                    ban_count++; 
                    ban_flag_refresh(); 
                    printf("Ошибка входа\nОсталось попыток %d\n", 3-ban_count); 
                    system("pause"); 
                    start_menu();
                }
            break;
        case 2:
            enter_perm='a';
            if (enter()){
                ban_flag=0; ban_count=0; ban_time=0; ban_flag_refresh();
                a_menu();
            } else{
                    ban_count++; 
                    ban_flag_refresh(); 
                    printf("Ошибка входа\nОсталось попыток %d\n", 3-ban_count); 
                    system("pause"); 
                    start_menu();
                }
            break;
        case 1:
            enter_perm='u';
            if (enter()){
                ban_flag=0; ban_count=0; ban_time=0; ban_flag_refresh();
                u_menu();
            } else{
                    ban_count++; 
                    ban_flag_refresh(); 
                    printf("Ошибка входа\nОсталось попыток %d\n", 3-ban_count); 
                    system("pause"); 
                    start_menu();
                }
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("Выбран выход из программы\n");
            sleep(1);
            exit(1);
    }
```

Здравствуйте. Вот код моей функции для логина. При работе со стрелками вверх/вниз все нормально работает, но при нажатии любой другой клавиши(даже не стрелок влево/вправо) меню не будет работать пока не нажмешь заново на какую-либо клавишу не стрелку. Вроде как-то по индексу из первого гетча можно проверить, но

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Проверил код стрелок с помощью

```
    while (1){
        if (kbhit()){
            q=getch();
            printf("%d ", q);
            q=getch();
            printf("%d\n", q);
        }
    }
```

Вот такого цикла. У меня вышло так, что первый отсылаемый код равен -32. Заменив

```
if (choice==0xE0 || choice==0 || choice==224)
```

На

```
if (choice==-32)
```

Все заработало